# Configuring \ref for different levels of enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, ref

The standard behavior for the `\ref` command in a layered enumerate environment creates references with this structure: enumi_label.enumii_label. I would like to configure the `\ref` command so that the reference *only* prints the second-level label. This is perhaps easiest to understand with an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bar\label{item:2}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Sub-foo.\label{item:3}
\item sub-bar.\label{item:4}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Actual output: %
(\ref{item:2}); (\ref{item:3}); (\ref{item:4}).

Desired output: (1); (a); (b)

\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output.

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to do this without new packages in order to avoid conflicts with other code I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote,

> Ideally, I'd like to do this without new packages

In that case, simply insert the following lines of code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\makeatother
```

In case you're curious: For every counter -- say, `mycounter` -- that LaTeX creates, it automatically creates a "prefix macro" -- called `\p@mycounter` in the present example -- that specifies what (if anything) should be prefixed to a counter in a cross-reference situation. For most counters, the associated prefix macro is empty, i.e., nothing is prefixed. However, as you've discovered, for the counters `enumii`, `enumiii`, and `enumiv`, the prefix macros actually do something. For instance, the default value of `\p@enumii` is `\theenumi`. To unset this setting, it's necessary to run a `\renewcommand` directive.

Aside: The directives `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are needed to remove the "TeX-special" property of the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
\makeatletter
\let\p@enumii\@empty
\makeatother
```

lets you get rid of the 'leading' item number. Proceed with care if you do this in case you have multiple first-level lists: Things could get confusing.

---

In case you do want to use an external package, [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) can do this for you as well

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumii}
```